# Primefaces Accordion + Datatable filter / Multiple select not working as expected

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a search screen that displays data grouped together based on the search value. This is how the display is accomplished. I have a `p:accordionpanel` that gets dynamically populated from the back end bean. I have a `p:datatable` with in the `p:accordianpanel`. There can be more than one accordion panel that gets displayed each containing a datatable. The display works as expected.

**Problem:** I have implemented filter and multiple selection of rows on the  datatables. If there are more than 1 datatable that gets populated, the filter and search only works on the last datatable. The `selection` and `filteredValue` attributes of the `p:datatable` are bound to separate objects. If I click on any of the "Select All" boxes, the rows from the last table gets selected. I would expect the rows on the table that's associated with the "Select All" check box to be selected.

Here's the accordion / datatable:

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true"
                  value="#{basicSearchResultsVO.sortedMessages}" var="sortedMessages">
    <p:tab title="#{sortedEdiMessages.key}">
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable"
                     emptyMessage="No Data found with searched criteria"
                     filteredValue="#{sortedMessages.value.filteredMessages}"
                     rowKey="#{message.archiveSequenceI}"
                     rows="10"
                     selection="#{sortedMessages.value.selectedMessages}"
                     sortBy="#{message.msgDateTimeTs}" sortOrder="descending"
                     value="#{sortedMessages.value.messages}" var="message"
                     widgetVar="messagesTable">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel style="text-align: right;margin:3px;">
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('messagesTable').filter()" style="width:150px;" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            ...

        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>

    ...

</p:accordionPanel>
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Would appreciate your assistance and feed back.

Answer (score 3):

OK. I found the issue with the code. Had to make the `widgetVar` attribute on the datatable unique for the filter / multi select to work correctly on each datatable. Here's the modified code. The only change is to the `widgetVar` attribute of the `p:datatable` and the `onkeyup` attribute of `p:inputText` bound to a unique value provided by the backend bean.

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true"
                  value="#{basicSearchResultsVO.sortedMessages}" var="sortedMessages">
    <p:tab title="#{sortedEdiMessages.key}">
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable"
                     emptyMessage="No Data found with searched criteria"
                     filteredValue="#{sortedMessages.value.filteredMessages}"
                     rowKey="#{message.archiveSequenceI}"
                     rows="10"
                     selection="#{sortedMessages.value.selectedMessages}"
                     sortBy="#{message.msgDateTimeTs}" sortOrder="descending"
                     value="#{sortedMessages.value.messages}" var="message"
                     widgetVar="#{sortedEdiMessages.key}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel style="text-align: right;margin:3px;">
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('#{sortedEdiMessages.key}').filter()" style="width:150px;" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            ...

        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>

    ...

</p:accordionPanel>
```